# Probability numbers from 1-10

Tags: probability

I have a problem containing probablility and don't know how to solve it ?

Numbers from 1 to 10 are ordered randomly.
What is the probability that 1 2 3 appear in the sequence in that particular order - allow other numbers to be between them.

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do not consider 1,2,3 and focus instead on numbers from 4 to 10.
They can occur in 6! ways (ordered randomly).
you have to multiply 6! for the number of ways in which (1,2,3) can present themselves in the sequence( for example, 123 can be at the beginning of the number, in the middle(allow other numbers to be between them)or at the end.
The number of positions of (1,2,3) inside a sequence of ten numbers are the combinations without repetition ten, three.
So favourable cases 6! per C(10,3)/10!(number of possibilities).

Comment: 4 though 10 is seven numbers-you have a fencepost error.  They can appear in 7! ways.  With that correction you come out right.  But you are making this much more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The relevant numbers $1,2,3$ can appear in $3!=6$ different orders that have equal probability to occur.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it, because yes it could be right if the they are in order 1,2,3, but it might be something like that 1,10,7,2,5,6,3,4,8,9 and it is still correct, there is no chance that is only 6 orders I think

Comment: You only have to look at the numbers $1,2,3$. The others are irrelevant. There is no reason to believe that order $1,10,7,2,5,6,3,4,8,9$ has more or less probability to occur than e.g. $2,10,7,1,5,6,3,4,8,9$ where $1$ and $2$ are switched.

Comment: So how about that:
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10 next 
1.4.2.3.5.6.7.8.9.10 next
1.5.2.3.4,5.6.7.8.9.10 next
1.6.2.3.4.5.7.8.9.10 next
1.7.2.3.4.5.6.8.9.10 next
1.8.2.3.4.5.6.7.9.10 next
1.9.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.10 next

And so on... theres more than only 6 orders

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that $\dots1\dots2\dots3\dots$ will occur more or less often than $\dots2\dots1\dots3\dots$?

Comment: No there's not
So we have 10! of all cohabitation and only 6 is correct ?

Comment: If you restrict to the relevant numbers $1,2,3$ then there are only $6$ orders: $.1.2.3.$, $.1.3.2.$, $.2.1.3.$, $.2.3.1.$, $.3.1.2.$ and $.3.2.1.$ all having equal propability to occur and exactly one of them will indeed occur, so the probability that $.1.2.3.$ will be the one that occurs is $\frac16$